# Thread join(milliseconds) not killing thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, timeout, java-threads

I am trying to timeout a running Thread with a Thread.join(millis), but it just hangs and does not timeout. What could be the cause of this? Sample code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    final Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000000000000000L; i++) {
        }
    });
    t1.start();
    t1.join(100);
    System.out.println("t1.join called");
}
```

Comment: Works for me: https://ideone.com/qTUHCz

Comment: `t1.join called` is displayed, but the JVM won't exit because the `Thread` is none daemon, so it will wait until it's completed. `join(int)` is the amount of time the "current" thread will wait for the thread in question to end, if it reaches the time out value, the method will simply return, it has no effect on the running thread

Comment: @shmosel Ah, actually that page says Time limit exceeded #stdin #stdout 5s 4837376KB, meaning that I think the engine running that code snippet doesn't let code run for more than 5s, if you try running this in your IDE, it might have a different behavior

Comment: works for me too

Comment: @MadProgrammer, Ah, thank you so much, this was driving me nuts because the docs says "Waits at most millis milliseconds for this thread to die." which I thought implied that it will kill the thread if has waited past the limit. That makes sense, it is just waiting that long for it to finish, and if past that limit, the join will return and the caller thread can continue to do whatever it wants

Comment: @ shmosel and Bishoy, I'm sorry I wasn't clear about the question. The standard output will print "t1.join called", but the Thread t1 will still be running, which was what I was confused about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Thread join(milliseconds) not killing thread in Java

It's not meant to kill the thread. It is meant to wait for it to exit up to the timeout value, and then to throw `InterruptedException` to the *current* thread if the timeout expired. See the Javadoc.

Comment: Yes, @MadProgrammer has already answered this one, but accepted because it is what he/she said which is correct

Comment: And you also added the InterruptedException bit, which I figured out but havent been mentioned which might help others

Comment: Nowhere in the method Javadoc for JDK 7, 8, and 11 it says that `join(long)` throws when the timeout expires.